# Smooth Scroll Using window.scrollBy

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to smoothly scroll a page using setInterval() and window.scrollBy()

I would use jQuery's animate function, but the animation needs to be continuous and loop infinitely (the page contents will be infinite).

The idea is fairly simple:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 1;

setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0, x);
}, y);
```

**How can I increase the scroll speed without making the animation appear jumpy?**

I'm experience two problems:

1. setInterval() can't take a Y value less than 1 (or probably closer to 30, depending on browser limits)
2. Increasing the value of X causes the animation to be jumpy (due to pixels being skipped altogether)

Here's a fiddle to experiment with:

http://jsfiddle.net/eoojrqh6/2/

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish something like this:
http://skifreeonline.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than `window.scrollBy` you can use `window.scroll`.

http://jsfiddle.net/peterdotjs/f7yzLzyx/1/

```
var x = 1; //y-axis pixel displacement
var y = 1; //delay in milliseconds

setInterval(function() {
    window.scroll(0, x);
    x = x + 5; //if you want to increase speed simply increase increment interval
}, y);
```

As you currently have `y` value set very low, you can adjust the values of `y` and the incremental value of `x` to find the desired scroll speed.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working well. Looks like the trick is keep that Y value as small as possible. I'll mark this as answered after some more testing.

Comment: For the record, [window.scroll is not supported on Edge, IE, or Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll#Browser_Compatibility).

Comment: Love you soo much, you just saved my time a lot. thank you so much

Answer (score 17):

Use `behavior` option instead of `setInterval` its more simple and it's the right way to do this,

```
var x = 1;
var y = 1;

window.scrollBy({
    top: x,
    left: y,
    behavior : "smooth"
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also scroll other elements:

```js
document.querySelector('.el-class').scrollBy({
  top: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to just auto-scrolling on any page with a click, I created a bookmark that I placed on my bookmark toolbar so it's always visible and accessible with a single click of the mouse. Then I just edited it's properties with this code that simply auto-scrolls the page when clicked, if the page isn't auto-scrolling. If it is already auto-scrolling, then it simply stops it so you can turn on auto-scrolling and turn off auto-scrolling by just clicking on it. Here is the code I saved in the bookmark as the location, just copy the following code and then open up any browser, either right click on any existing bookmarks on your toolbar and goto properties, then paste the code or create new bookmark and paste the code as the Location if using Firefox

> javascript:var%20isScrolling;%20var%20scrolldelay;%20function%20pageScroll()%20{%20window.scrollBy(2,1);%20scrolldelay%20=%20setTimeout('pageScroll()',.1);%20isScrolling%20=%20true;%20}%20if(isScrolling%20!=%20true)%20{%20pageScroll();%20}%20else%20{%20isScrolling%20=%20false;%20clearTimeout(scrolldelay);%20}

**For Internet Explorer & Chrome, use this code that doesn't contain the %20 for spaces**

> javascript:var isScrolling; var scrolldelay; function pageScroll() { window.scrollBy(0,1); scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',15); isScrolling = true; } if(isScrolling != true) { pageScroll(); } else { isScrolling = false; clearTimeout(scrolldelay); }

Just edit the values to change the speed according to your own preference for what looks best on your computer since the effect won't be the same unanymously for every display

Answer (score 0):

**Solutuon for 2020**
you can use the `scrollTo` function which has the behavior property of `smooth`, so your code be as follows.

```
//Excluding event listener functions.
//one liner solutions for scrolling to the bottom and top of a document.

const footer = document.body.scrollHeight;
const scrollDown = (footer)=>{
return window.scrollTo({top: footer, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Scroll to the top by simply reducing the top properties value to zero.

```
const nav = 0;
const scrollUp = ()=>{
return window.scrollTo({top: nav, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```